# Two ships, one year apart, travelling from earth to a distant planet. What is the time difference of arrival?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, speed-of-light

If a ship set off at a significant percentage of the speed of light, and landed on a distant planet, and then a second ship set off a year or so later, what would the time distance be at the destination planet?

Does the time dilation change depending on if the ships are travelling at the same time? Say if the 'on ship' duration of the journey was ten years, and the second ship set out while the first one was still travelling, would they arrive with the same gap as what they set out with?

Or, since the ship that has reached the destination has slowed down/ landed before the second ship, would the time dilation change the time gap at that end?

So, for instance, if a person were on the second ship, would their perception of the journey be 'a year ago the first ship set off, now we set off, it's a ten year journey, we arrive and find that the first ship arrived a year before we did' or would there be time differences due to the two ships setting off at different times?

Does travelling at a significant percentage of the speed of light and the time dilation effect change whether you're travelling toward or away from something? Like would the perception of the ship's journey be different from earth than from the target planet in terms of time?

I'd appreciate any answers, though I'm dumb as a brick and don't understand mathematics, so simple explanations would be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid you _really_ do need the mathematics to get anywhere!  To really understand this you need a good textbook, not YouTube videos. Also, you need to be painfully specific about saying things like "a year ago" and "at the same time".  Everything in SR has its own clock, there is no "universal" time.

Comment: This would fall under the "homework-type-question" rule (IMO).  It's all material you can look up and check on e.g. Wikipedia or through tutorials on YouTube or a web search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persons A and B are traveling. Both would experience the same trip duration: ten years.  B would spend a year waiting for his turn to depart.  A would spend a year waiting for  B to arrive and join him.  Their clocks and calendars would read the same when B arrives.

Answer (score 1):

Two ships are leaving Earth. We are assuming that both have the same engines, and accelerate the same way.

Both will experience the same travel duration.

While the first ship has already left Earth, the second ship is still waiting on Earth for a year on his clock (on Earth).

Now after the first ship arrives on the new planet, it waits for a year, but that year ticks on his clock on another planet. There might be a different gravitational zone on that new planet, so on the first ship's clock the waiting time while it is already on the new planet waiting for the second ship might be different from a year.

When the second ship arrives, their clocks might show different times because:

1. the first ship was already in flight while the second ship was on Earth, in a different gravitational field, this causes GR time dilation
2. now when the first ship is already on the new planet, and waits for the second planet, they are in a different gravitational zone, so this causes GR time dilation

If they accelerate the same way, and travel the same speed, then there is no SR time dilation. But there might be GR time dilation.

Comment: It seems to me that these arguments are unneccessarily complicated. Just think of more than two ships: a third ship relates to the second like the second to the first. A fourth ship relates to the third like the third to the second, and so on. Non of the pairings is special w.r.t. the others. This means they all will arrive with the same time difference.